# Distance to nearest hub using raster data QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I'm trying to figure out if in QGIS 3.10, there is a way to obtain the distance of each raster pixel from a line feature (a vector)?

I'm quite familiar with the "distance from nearest hub" using vector data but I'm a bit lost when it comes to raster data. The idea would be to obtain the distance of each pixel from a line representing the border of Vietnam. Coordinate set at UTM48N for Vietnam.